# Parse PDF to PPTX (in asp.net or python or javascript)

Tags: python, javascript, parser, asp.net, powerpoint

I'm looking for a service that allows me to convert `pdf` files to `pptx`.
The need is to output a PowerPoint that is not simply the conversion of the pdf into images, but that is also editable (therefore it includes OCR technology).
Services may be manageable on `asp.net` but `python` or `javascript` are fine too.
I tried a few services but none of them really met my need.

Libraries / modules that did not work:

```
Aspose.PDF (aspnet);
Cloudmersive (aspnet);
Convertapi (aspnet);
Spire.Presentation (aspnet);
pdf2pptx (python);
pdf-powerpoint (nodejs)
```

Would anyone know how to point me to other services or ways to get this type of PowerPoint output?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using the [`Zamzar File Conversion API Service`](https://developers.zamzar.com/)

With this service (which can be called up in almost all programming languages) we were able to convert from `PDF` to `PPTX` and output a perfectly identical file (page formats, styles, etc.) to the PDF with the possibility of editing it (it does not generate image slides but fully editable slides).